# Ajuda com gravação de Decimal .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um sistema em `.NET CORE 2.2` onde estou enfrentando um problema na gravação de números decimais no banco de dados `MySQL`.

Usando como exemplo o `decimal` `19.99`:

- Pelo MAC grava corretamente;
- Pelo Windows grava incorretamente o valor: `1999.00`;

Pesquisei bastante algumas soluções, porém nenhuma funcionou para mim...

Acredito que possa ser algum problema de cultura.

**VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label>Valor</label>
  <input asp-for="Valor" type="text" class="form-control" id="decimal" value="@try{ @ViewBag.Chamado.Valor} catch{}">
</div>
```

**MODEL**

```
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
public void Gravar()
{
    DAL objDAL = new DAL();
    string sql = string.Empty;
    if (Id != null)
    {
        sql = $"UPDATE chamados SET titulo='{Titulo}', descricao='{Descricao}', pa_id='{PA}', equipamento_id='{Equipamento}', valor='{Valor}', status_id='{Status}' WHERE id='{Id}'";
    }
    else
    {
        string Data_Abertura = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        sql = "INSERT INTO chamados (titulo, descricao, pa_id, equipamento_id, data_abertura, valor, status_id)" + $" VALUES ('{Titulo}', '{Descricao}', '{PA}', '{Equipamento}', '{Data_Abertura}', '{Valor}', '{Status}')";
    }
    objDAL.ExecutarComandoSQL(sql);
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult NovoChamado(int? id )
{     
    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Chamado = new ChamadosModel().RetornarChamado(id);
    }
    CarregarDados();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "Mvc.ViewNotResolved")]
    public IActionResult NovoChamado(ChamadosModel chamado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CarregarDados();
            chamado.Gravar();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }    
        return View();
    }
    private void CarregarDados()
    {
        ViewBag.ListaEquipamentos = new ChamadosModel().RetornarListaEquipamentos(); 
        ViewBag.ListaPA = new PAModel().ListarTodosPA();  
        ViewBag.ListaStatus = new StatusModel().ListarTodosStatus(); 
    }
}
```

**SETANDO CULTURA**

```
 // Definindo a cultura padrão: pt-BR
 var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") };
 app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
 {
       DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR"),
       SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
       SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
 });
```

Comment: O seu código parece ser vulnerável a SQL Injection. Considere usar prepared statements nas suas consultas. Exemplo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: A primeira coisa é porque você você está passando o campo `valor` como string. E se substituir as interpolações por SQLCommands e SQL Parameters que são tipados?

Comment: Com relação ao SQL Injection vou dar uma estudada, como e ela vai ser usada apenas internamente em servidor local não e uma prioridade no momento. @LeandroAngelo poderia me explicar como fazer isso? Ainda estou no inicio dos meus estudos e não compreendi o que devo fazer nesse caso.

Comment: Prioridade é fazer o código sem SQL Injection, existe a maneira correta de fazer isso e você está na contra mão e por isso tem outros problemas além do que o Leandro citou ...

Comment: Como você digita a informação no Windows e como você digita informação no MAC?

Comment: da mesma maneira, usando o ".", se tendo com "," recebo erro em ambos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema parece ser que o tipo do seu input é text, quando na verdade deveria ser number, com o atributo steps:

```
<input asp-for="Valor" type="number" step="any">
```

Comment: Eu ja havia testado assim, nessa maneira funciona a gravação, o problema e que quando seto assim não consigo carregar os valores quando vou editar a solicitação, ele nesse caso fica em branco. Por isso estou usando o campo text e usando um jquery para evitar que seja digitado "," e formatando os números

Comment: Acabei de testar novamente aqui trocando o type para "number" e no windows continua o problema, no mac normal, apenas com o problema de quando editar não carrega